# using a button to switch between two states

Tags: javascript, html, css

Essentially I want to use a button to bring a div to the front using the CSS `z-index` and then when pressing the button again I want it to revert back to its original state.

This is the code I have got so far and it will happily change it first time round but it wont revert it back.

```
function thumbnail(){
    if (document.getElementById("div").style.zIndex= -3){
        document.getElementById("div").style.zIndex= -2;
    }

    if  (document.getElementById("div").style.zIndex= -2){
        document.getElementById("div").style.zIndex= -3;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Use `=` for assignment, `==` for comparison

Comment: Your second `if` needs to be `else` instead! Otherwise both blocks always execute sequentially.  As soon as the first changes to `-2`, the second will change it immediately back to `-3`.

Comment: What @onon15 is referring to specifically is this:  `if (...zIndex == -3) { ...zIndex = -2; }` Note the `==` in the `if()` condition.

Answer (score 4):

```
function thumbnail(){
    var depth = document.getElementById("div").style.zIndex;
    document.getElementById("div").style.zIndex = (depth == -3)? -2 : -3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This slightly more efficient version avoids traversing the DOM more than once:

```
function thumbnail () {
    var elStyle = document.getElementById ("div").style;
    elStyle.zIndex = elStyle.zIndex == -3 ? -2 : -3;
}
```

Using `div` as an id may prove to be confusing when you return to this code later, use a name which identifies the function of the div.